# I have a google form feeding into google sheet and I need it to pickup all the hyperlinks that have been submitted and drop them in a created folder

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google form that feeds into a google sheet.

I need the below script to pick up all hyperlinks across all columns to be picked up and added to the folder - There could also be multiple hyperlinks in one column.

The below was set up for one hyperlink but I have tried a few things and hit the limit of my knowledge.

`

````
function filter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form responses 1');
  var data = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(),1,1,ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  var dataToCopy = [];

  dataToCopy.push(data[0],
  data[1],
  data[2],
  data[3],
  data[4],
  data[5],
  data[6],
  data[7],
  data[8],
  data[9],
  data[10],
  data[11],
  data[12],
  data[13],
  data[14],
  data[15],
  data[16],
  data[17],
  data[18],
  data[19],
  data[20],
  data[21],
  data[22],
  data[23],
  data[24],
  data[25],
  data[26],
  data[27],
  data[28],
  data[29],
  data[30],
  data[31],
  data[32],
  data[33],
  data[34],
  data[35],
  data[36],
  data[37],
  data[38],
  data[39],
  data[40],
  data[41],
  data[42],
  data[43],
  data[44],
  data[45],
  data[46],
  data[47],
  data[48],
  data[49],
  data[50],
  data[51],
  data[52],
  data[53],
  data[54],
  data[55],
  data[56],
  data[57],
  data[58],
  data[59],
  data[60],
  data[61],
  data[62],
  data[63],
  data[64],
  data[65],
  data[66],
  data[67],
  data[68],
  data[69],
  data[70],
  data[71],
  data[72],
  data[73],
  data[74],
  data[75],
  data[76],
  data[77],
  data[78],
  data[79],
  data[80],
  data[81],
  data[82],
  data[83],
  data[84],
  data[85],
  data[86],
  data[87],
  data[88],
  data[89],
  data[90],
  data[91],
  data[92],
  data[93],
  data[94],
  data[95],
  data[96],
  data[97],
  data[98],
  data[99],
  data[100],

                      );
  copyToProjectTab(dataToCopy,data)
}



function copyToProjectTab(dataToCopy,allData){
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form responses 1');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Response Folder Generation');
  
  var orgRow = ss1.getLastRow();
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow()+1;
  
  var ref = "JLSIR." + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+1","yy") + "." + orgRow;

  dataToCopy.unshift(ref);
  
  ss.getRange(lastRow,1,1,dataToCopy.length).setValues([dataToCopy]);

  var documents = ss.getRange(lastRow,20).getValue()
  
  createFolder(lastRow,ref,documents,allData)
  }



function createFolder(rowNumber,refNumber,documents){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Response Folder Generation');

  var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER LINK').createFolder(refNumber);

  var uploads = [];

  if(documents != ''){
    uploads = documents.split(',');
 
  }

 if (uploads.length > 0){
  
    for (var i = 0 ; i <= uploads.length-1 ; i++){
      var id = uploads[i].match(/[-\w]{25,}/);

      DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(newFolder);

    }
  }
  ss.getRange(rowNumber,1).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("'+newFolder.getUrl()+'","'+refNumber+'")');
  
  ss.getRange(rowNumber,150).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("'+newFolder.getUrl()+'","'+newFolder.getUrl()+'")')

}```
`

I have tried amending the code to the whole last row but I have no idea anymore.
````

Comment: In the cells that have multiple hyperlinks what is the delimiter?

Comment: Hi Cooper its just a comma ", "

Answer (score 0):

So I understand that you have a sheet where users input their answers and one of the fields asked is for links delimited by a comma and you want to get those links out of a the sheet and do something with them later on, right?

Well, in that case Apps Script has the findAll() method to find all the links, you could do this with a regex that checks for http* until it gets to a comma, for example, then you can do as you wish with them like putting them on an array.

These two links have examples on how to use that method with a regular expresion [[1]](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/39f719bd10ccbb27edd694c33242e496) [[2]](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/regex-search-using-textfinder)

Comment: Appreciate the answer - I am not sure how to do that are you able to help me?